# How can i customize my url using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

**#how can i change this url? #**

```
http://www.domain.in/product-category.php?id=3&name=house-hold&type=top-category
```

*to*

```
http://www.domain.in/product-category/house-hold
```

**using .htaccess.**

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Where did `id=3` go? How will you know the id from your new URL? Same for `type=top-category` it is missing from the new URL, so both cannot really be equivalent or the first URL contains data which is redundant/unused

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.in
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.*)&type
RewriteRule (.*).php /$1/%1?
```

```
Line 1 : we check the domain
Line 2 : we save the parameter name in a var (%1)
Line 3 : we rewrite rule with $1 (`REQUEST_URI` before `.php`) and %1.
```

https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=71f3a8dd-6b81-4620-b02c-2ae47297c8fc